# How to extract Babel generated code from webpack bundles into a new chunk

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm working on component-level code splitting, using Webpack 4. This means that a single page could have many entry points loaded.

I've got the entry points being generated dynamically, based on a naming convention.  The last issue I'm solving for is de-duping the generated code from Babel.

I'm using class syntax, so Babel adds `_classCallCheck`, `_defineProperties`, and `_createClass` to the specific entry (and even duplicates it across `import` statements).  I had a similar problem to this with the webpack runtime, however that was resolved by using the runtimeChunk option.  Is there anything similar for Babel? Ideally, it seems, the Babel helpers would be loaded as a separate chunk, and then passed in as a dependency to the webpack chunk. A sample of the bundle

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["footer"],{
...
...
},[["./src/Feature/WireFraming/code/scripts/footer.js","runtime"]]]);
```

might become

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["footer"],{
...
...
},[["./src/Feature/WireFraming/code/scripts/footer.js","runtime","babel-runtime"]]]);
```

I looked through the webpack docs, and couldn't seem to find anything.  Since babel is a pre-processor, I don't believe that splitChunks takes care of this.

Hoping that someone else has experienced something similar.

Comment: Are you looking for https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-runtime?

Comment: I'm going to go check on this. I think this is exactly what I need. I'll let you know.

Comment: Adding @babel/plugin-transform-runtime to my bablerc just increased my bundle size.  something is missing.

Comment: Not sure what to say, hard to say more without a more complete reproducible example.

Comment: I'll try to post the whole example.  Is there a good spot to put that?

Comment: Ideally include the webpack/babel configs and a sample file in the question and maybe link to a github repo with a more complete example?

Comment: So, I was mistaken.  The correct bundles are being outputted.  However, none of the "dependent" bundles are being loaded by my entry, in the browser. i.e. headerComponent.js has a class that relies on component.js.  i.e. class HeaderComponent extends Component.  That's being transformed correctly, but it doesn't seem to actually load the dependency.

Comment: This appears to be due to the "entries" not being executed.  Each of these "entries" represents a component rendering that exists on the current page, so I need a way to initialize those imports.  Trying to use Promise.all([list of dynamic imports]).then(x => x.default()) throws an error, saying default is not defined, although each of my modules exports default.  I assume this is some function of webpack bundles.